# Is there a way to centralize users of multiple postgres databases to manage their permissions through AWS Cognito or Keycloack?

Tags: linux, postgresql, amazon-web-services, keycloak, amazon-cognito

I have several individual EC2 machines running postgres server 15. The assumption covered here is: postgres roles and passwords. I have problems because every time a user on my team needs to change the password of their DB role or if I need to assign or revoke grants in tables (DB objects) I need to do it machine by machine one by one. I need a way to centralize these users in a single location and configure each machine in pg_hba.conf to allow authentication using one of the protocols mentioned above or another way. Someone help me?

I tried searching the documentation for these tools and didn't find satisfactory answers.